# PAGEIOLATCH_SH Does Not Release In SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, block

I have a stored procedure running on SQL Server 2014 with the strangest issue.

The procedure, which is admittedly complex, runs in SSMS in about 2 seconds.  It runs as a job under the SQL Agent in at most 2 seconds.

The same stored procedure, when called by a .Net web service, hits a permanent PAGEIOLATCH_SH block and will not run in even 5 or 10 minutes.  Even after adding every conceivable index, clearing the cached plans repeatedly, shrinking the log file, clearing disk space, and rebooting the server.

What could possibly account for this behavior?

Comment: When you say PAGEIOLATCH_SH does not release, do you mean you see different latches held for the duration of the query or the same latch? Latches are usually short-lived. Regarding the performance difference, itt is probably different plans. TL;DR [see this article](https://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html).

Comment: Yes.  The query never executes.  I am watching in the SSMS activity monitor, which may not show all activity.

Comment: I can confirm there are different plans for the SSMS query vs the one from the web service.  I don't know what the difference is.  One other detail I forgot to mention, the web service query was working correctly for a year or so prior to developing the issue above.

Comment: @DanGuzman thanks for the article.  It's going to take a little time to read it.